# Django: Creating a navigation bar splitted in two parts with elements styled differently (HTML, CSS, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I am trying to create a search button in a responsive navigation bar.
The navigation bar has a media query in the CSS file that reduces it to a dropdown list according to the dimension of the reader's screen.

The html of the navigation bar is the following:

```
  <nav class="navbarSection">
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="http://www...">Chi Siamo e Cosa Facciamo</a>
      <a href="http://www...">Storia di Gabriella</a>
      <a href="#articles">Tutti gli Articoli</a>
      <a href="http://www...">Video Gallery</a>
      <a href="http://www...">Photo Gallery</a>
      <a href="http://www...">Dicono di Noi</a>
      <a href="http://www...">Come Contattarci</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="respScreen()">&#9776;</a>
      <a class="material-icons" style="font-size:32px;color:white;">search</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

And this is the CSS related:

```
/* Add a red background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
    background-color: #aa2222;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #d9bb56;
    color: black;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.active {
    background-color: #d9bb56;
    color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}

/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home").
Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
  .topnav a {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: left;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon.
This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

/* Style of the search button inside the navigation bar */

.material-icons {
float: right
width: 52px !important;
font-size: 20px !important;
padding-top: 11px !important;
padding-bottom: 13px !important;
}
```

This is the actual result in responsive design mode with Firefox, emulating an Iphone 6s

Below the outcome with the Menu closed:

[image: As is menu closed]

Below the outcome with the dropdown list opened

[image: As is menu opened]

I have made with Pinta Image Editor the desired result with the Menu closed:

[image: To be menu closed]

And below with the menu opened

[image: To be menu opened]

To obtain the desired result, I tried to split the navbar in two different `div`s but it seems to create another navbar on the bottom of the first instead of put them both inline (see code below):

HTML

```
<nav class="navbarSection">
        <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
          <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
          <a href="http://www...">Chi Siamo e Cosa Facciamo</a>
          <a href="http://www...">Storia di Gabriella</a>
          <a href="#articles">Tutti gli Articoli</a>
          <a href="http://www...">Video Gallery</a>
          <a href="http://www...">Photo Gallery</a>
          <a href="http://www...">Dicono di Noi</a>
          <a href="http://www...">Come Contattarci</a>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="respScreen()">&#9776;</a>
        <div class="rightNavbar">
          <button>
            <a class="material-icons" style="font-size:32px color:white;">search</a>
          </button>
        </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.rightNavbar {
float: right
}

navbarSection {
float: left
}
```

The full repository of the project is [here](https://github.com/marcogdepinto/DjangoWeb) if needed

**EDIT 1**: added code for possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution

Create a div container for the general navbar and displayed its elements inline

HTML

```
  <section class="navbarSection">
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="http://www....">Chi Siamo e Cosa Facciamo</a>
      <a href="http://www....">Storia di Gabriella</a>
      <a href="#articles">Tutti gli Articoli</a>
      <a href="http://www....">Video Gallery</a>
      <a href="http://www....">Photo Gallery</a>
      <a href="http://www....">Dicono di Noi</a>
      <a href="http://www...">Come Contattarci</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="respScreen()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
    <div class="right-nav" id="myRightNav">
      <a class="material-icons" style="font-size:32px;color:white;">search</a>
    </div>
  </section>
```

CSS

```
.navbarSection {
display: inline;
}

.topnav {
float:left
}

.right-nav {
float:right;
background-color: #aa2222;
overflow: hidden;
}
```